Extract data from web that isn't detected as a table
I'm struggling getting data from the web to Excel, as it isn't detected as a table. There was a similar case reported (How to get data to excel from web that the data is not in a table?), but I have no idea how the solution proposed works, as I really don't know much about queries and others...
I basically need to extract revenue from Euronext Website.
URL : https://live.euronext.com/fr/product/equities/FR0014005AC9-XPAR/company-information
The data I want is in red in this screenshot.
Data to extract:

It's weird as the web preview in Excel seems to be missing almost all the body of the website (see the image): 
This is what info Excel detects data detection
I'm comfortable with VBA, but I have no idea on how to interact with a website whatsoever. All ideas on how to overcome this issue are much appreciated!
I tried the Get data built in feature in Excel, but it didn't recognize the table.

It looks like this is in a table called key-figures-table-en  Do you mean you've tried the Data --> Web way and cant see the table?

Worked fine for me using the Data -> From Web. Comes up as Table 2

Hey Nathan_Sav, and chitown88. I've added a screenshot (called data detection) in the thread to show that I don't get any data. Thanks !
